# Removing binaries from an hg repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial, binaryfiles

Is it possible with Mercurial to remove all files with a certaain extension? I did an addremove and then all my binary .pyc were versioned and now I get this stopper when I do versioning:

```
tool kdiff3 can't handle binary
tool docdiff can't handle binary
 no tool found to merge bnano-www/wtforms/widgets.pyc
keep (l)ocal or take (o)ther? o
19 files updated, 67 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

C:\Users\developer\bnano\bnano-www>
```

I don't really know what it means except I can press o for other and go on with my work. Now I'd like to clean my repository and optimal would be to be able to do an addremove without binaries getting added but I think it is not possible.

Can you give some recommendation what to do in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### HgIgnore

First of all, you can add some rules to the [.hgignore](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/.hgignore) file to tell Mercurial that you want to ignore some files. Then, `hg addremove` won't add them automatically and they won't appear in the output of the commands (ie `hg status`) as untracked.

#### Removing the files

To remove your files, you can use `hg remove myfile`, for example, if all your `pyc` files are in the same directory, you can do `hg remove *.pyc` and then commit the change.

If your files are scattered in various repository, something like `hg remove -I *.pyc **/*` should remove all `.pyc` files in all directories.

#### Exclusion patterns

FYI, will it's better to add unwanted files in the `.hgignore` file, you can also tell `addremove` to ignore some files by doing `hg addremove -X *.pyc`. This will add/remove every files except those having the `pyc` extension.

You can find help about a specific mercurial command using `help`. For example, `hg help addremove`. In general everything is neatly explained !

#### Tutorial

To explore various Mercurial concepts in more depth, I recommand this excellent tutorial : http://hginit.com

Comment: Thank you. It was the ignore option that I was looking for. I'm still learning Mercurial and only knew the trivial operations this far.

Comment: Holymoly that hg remove -I *.pyc **/* not only removed the .pyc, but everything else! Beware

Answer (score 3):

To remove **all** binary files from a repository, you can use [Mercurial filesets](http://selenic.com/hg/help/filesets):

```
hg remove "set:binary()"
```

And as the other posters mentioned, it's a great idea to add unwanted extensions in the .hgignore file.

Comment: I know this is an old question and won't help the OP, but maybe this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove them like any other file `hg remove *.pyc`. You probably want to add .pyc to the .hgignore file to keep them from coming back when you use addremove.

In general though, you should be using `hg add` to selectively add files in the future, given that as the project develops, what files it contains should stabilize relatively quickly.